Nested sum of product of binomial numbers
I am currently working on an automata theory concerning a special case of nondeterministic automata. I am studying the state complexity of converting this automaton to a classical deterministic one (meaning: how many states will the deterministic automaton, which behaves as the nondeterministic one, have). This question arises from the case of the average state complexity problem. I came up with an upper bound for the average state complexity (I know it might sound weird) as a result of the structure I am dealing with. The bound is as follows:
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i} \binom{n}{j}}{2^n - 1}
$$
As one can see, this form is not really useful as it contains nested sums dependent on each other, which is not really comfortable. Of course, I am able to calculate the values, but I would like to have a better representation.
That's where I came up with an approximation of this equation which is:
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i} \binom{n}{j}}{2^n - 1} \leq
\frac{5}{8}\ 2^n
$$
The approximation is only slightly worse than the original equation, but in a much more convenient form.
I was able to check it only by calculating values and/or plotting the functions. But for further usage in other theories, I need to formally prove it.
As I am not an expert in combinatorics (and basically any other field in math), but as an informatician, I have some knowledge in this field.
What I tried:
I have tried to somehow simplify the left side of the inequality to show it holds for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Another way was to form a sequence of inequalities to somehow get to the desired result.
The last approach I used is an observation that for every $n \geq 4$, the original formula doubles. So if I can prove that instead, I can simply use mathematical induction to show the inequality.
All of my tries were unsuccessful. That's why I'm looking for help.
Is there a way to prove my approximation holds with any of my approaches or a different one?
Any help would be appreciated.

Hint: Find two times the numerator. You will need to observe that $\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}-1$ and $(2^n-1)^2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)^2$

@DS thank you for the hint but I am not really sure that I understand what you mean, especially the part 'Find two times the numerator'. Can you give me a little bit more insight?

for that you need to provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

provided additional context

Good. ioveri's answer sums up what I was hinting at.

Also, it looks like your inequality is very weak for $n$ large enough. Maybe not as useful in your work

Yes, I am aware of that, but for now, it is sufficient for me to show other theorems.

@simonhuraj I updated my answer

Thanks everyone for help.

I'll explain in details, but it will look a bit lengthy. First, observe that the sum in the nominator is
$$\begin{align}
S =&\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j = 1}^{i}\binom{n}{j}\right)
= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{i}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\\
=\,& \sum_{1 \leq j \leq i \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}
=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}
\\
\end{align}
$$
The idea is we combine the last two forms so that every summand corresponding to $j \leq i$ or $i < j$ appear once. Thus $i$ and $j$ can be freed from each other. We need to exclude those where $i = j$ since they are counted twice
$$\begin{align}
2S &= \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} + 
\sum_{1 \leq j \leq i \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\\
&= \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} + 
\sum_{1 \leq j < i \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} + \sum_{1\leq i = j \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\\
&= \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} + \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n}{i}^2\\
&= (2^{n}-1)^2+\binom{2n}{n}-1
\end{align}
$$
Hence the inequality is simplified to
$$(2^n-1)^2 + \binom{2n}{n} - 1\leq \frac{5}{4}\cdot 2^n(2^n-1)$$
which is simple to prove
EDIT: There's a mistake in the last line and I fixed it.
It is still simple to prove the inquality by observing that
$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}/\binom{2n}{n} = \dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2} < 2$$
thus $\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$ grows slowlier than $2^{n-2}$. By checking by hand we found that $\binom{10}{5} < 2^8$, hence $\binom{2n+2}{n+1} < 2^{n-2}$ for every $n \geq 8$. The rest is checking up to $n = 8$

Let's find the double summation:
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^n\left({n\choose i}\sum_{j=1}^i{n\choose j}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i{n\choose i}{n\choose j}$$
Notice that, if we were to switch indexes, the summation would be the same:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i{n\choose i}{n\choose j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j{n\choose j}{n\choose i}$$
This means
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i{n\choose i}{n\choose j}+\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\right)$$
Now we can rewrite the first term by changing the region of summation by an equivalent one:
$$\begin{aligned}
S&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j}^n{n\choose i}{n\choose j}+\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^j{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=j}^n{n\choose i}{n\choose j}+\sum_{i=1}^j{n\choose i}{n\choose j}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{n\choose i}{n\choose j}+{n\choose j}^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n{n\choose j}}_{2^n-1}\right)^2+\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n{n\choose j}^2}_{{2n\choose n}-1}\right]=\frac{(2^n-1)^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left({2n\choose n}-1\right)\
\end{aligned}$$
Now we can substitute this result in the inequality:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2(2^n-1)}\left[(2^n-1)^2+{2n\choose n}-1\right]&\leq\frac{5}{8}2^n\\
(2^n-1)^2+{2n\choose n}-1&\leq\frac{5}{8}2^{n+1}(2^n-1)\\
{2n\choose n}&\leq\frac{5}{8}2^{n}(2^{n+1}-2)-2^n(2^{n}-2)\\
{2n\choose n}&\leq 2^n\left(2^{n-2}+\frac{3}{4}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
And now you might be able to prove this by induction:
$$n=1:\frac{(2\cdot 1)!}{(1)!^2}=2\leq 2^1\left(2^{-1}+\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$n=2:\frac{(2\cdot 2)!}{(2)!^2}=6\leq 2^2\left(2^{2-2}+\frac{3}{4}\right)=7$$
Now we suppose this equality holds true for $n$ and check if it still does for $n+1$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!^2}&\leq 2^{n+1}\left(2^{n-1}+\frac{3}{4}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
It isn't as easy to prove as ioveri said though... I've been trying many alternatives an all were dead ends...

What are you talking about? It is indeed "easy": After collecting terms, we're left with $\binom{2n}{n} +0.75\times 2^n+0.25\times 4^n - 2 \ge 0$? What is difficult in this?

Could you post the proof at least to complement ioveri's answer then?

OK it seems that I made a sign mistake in the last line and I fixed it.
The inequality is still expected and not hard to prove since
$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}/\binom{2n}{n} = \dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2} < 2$
so it grows slowlier than $2^{n-2}$.
Once it get smaller than $2^{n-2}$ it is strictly smaller than the RHS for the rest of the cases.

I fixed my answer in accordance to that, thanks for noticing it @JoanS.GuillametF.

No problem, I see now more or less how to prove it.
